# Defining Line spacing between Header tags

Tags: html, tags

Is there a way of defining the line spacing between headers. I know using various header tags(h1, h2, h3) have various line spacing and I was wondering if there's a way of defining a line spacing for all of them, so that they are consistent and fluid throughout the page?

There are lots of articles on using margin and such, but I'm not too sure about it.

Comment: What about using css `line-height`?

Comment: You want to define the space between the bottom edge of one header element and the upper edge of the next header element? What's your HTML, what 'space' do you need? Have you tried anything at all, did something with your attempt not work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are not familiar with CSS I suggest reading a little:
CSS Intro: http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

CSS like this would set the line height for all of your header tags:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
  line-height: 30px; 
}
```

Or this would set top and bottom margin's for all headers:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
  margin-top:20px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The line-height property is specified as any one of the following:

- a number
- a length
- a percentage
- the keyword 'normal'.

The recommended method for defining line height is using a number value, referred to as a "unit-less" line height. A number value can be any number.

Most suggest using a line-height of 1.45 for h1~h6 so that would be written as:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1.45;
}
```

For further reading check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height